# Is there a difference between 記憶 and メモリー?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a difference between 記憶 and メモリー ?

Both words mean "memory".

Comment: Here's one factor: メモリーに記憶する sounds right but 記憶にメモリーする is debatable. i.e. one is more suited as a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

記憶 is the most normal word for "memory", or "information you remember".

メモリー is an English loanword, whose scope of use is far more limited. Today it most often means *memory* in computers. When referring to human memory, I guess it is usually a synonym of 思い出, which is closer to "reminiscence" or "past episode that evokes an emotion", or like *memory* in "fond memory", but still not used as frequent as its Japanese counterparts.

Note that 記憶 is also used as a computing term, but it means *store* or *storage* rather than *memory*.